# In python, how can we open a text file and replace move-statements with assignment operations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, io, stream

We want to modify a textfile using python. Specifically, we want to replace lines of the form:

```
MOV al, PTR[esi]
```

with:

```
al = PTR[esi]
```

It should work in general, and not only for `al` and `PTR[esi]`. In pseudo-code, we have:

```
pattern P = "$MOV "
The "$" in pattern P
represents either an empty string
or any character not in {abc...z} or {ABC...Z}

How To Convert Move Statements into Assignment Operations:
    open the file FILE_NAME as FILE
    for each line, LINE, in FILE:
        if LINE matches pattern P:
            do something special
        else:
            print LINE to FILE

How To Do Something Special:
    replace "MOV" with ""
    replace the leftmost comma character with "="
    write modified line to file.
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest is `line.replace()`, for example

```
with open(outfile,"w") as outf:
    with open(infile,"r") as inf:
      for line in inf:
        line = line.replace("MOV","")
        line = line.replace(", "," = ")
        ...
        print(line,file=outf)
```

Comment: An `if line.startswith('MOV ')` would do fine here - and then you wouldn't explicitely need the first `replace`-statement (i.e. only `line = line[4:].replace(", "," = ")
`)

Comment: Your code replaces commas with "=" on every single line, even if the line does not contain "MOV"

Comment: Your code replaces "MOV" when "MOV" is proceeded by other letters. For example, `ASIMOV` will become `ASI`. The pattern requires that "MOV" not be proceeded by an alphabet letter.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is ugly, but gets the job done:

```
 import re # regular expressions

 with open("write_file.py","w") as outf:
    with open("read_file.asm","r") as inf:
        for line in inf:
            search_target = "(^)([^_a-zA-Z0-9]*)(MOV)( )([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)( *)(,)(.*)"
            result = re.match(search_target, line, flags=re.I)
            if isinstance(result, type(None)):
                print(line, file=outf, end="")
            else:
                groups = [g for g in result.groups()]
                del groups[2]
                del groups[2]
                groups[4] = " = "
                print(''.join(groups), file=outf, end="")
```